# Traduction d'une phrase qui contient « epitomize »

Tags: traduction, anglais

> A spirit that it has epitomized better than all but a handful of
> classics ever since.
>
> Un esprit qu'il a incarné mieux que tout sauf une poignée de classiques depuis.

Dans ce contexte *incarner* rend-il en français correctement *epitomize* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui *epitomize* est bien traduit par *incarner*.

Le reste de la phrase est en revanche plus difficile à traduire. Voici ce que j'écrirais :

> Un esprit qu'il a remarquablement incarné et que très peu de classiques ont su mieux représenter depuis.